# Limiting list values based on previous field in QGIS Forms?

Tags: qgis, filter, value-list

Looking for assistance to set up appropriate configuration to enable drop-down lists values to be filtered based on a previous value.

Basically, I have a 3-tiered categorisation structure to one of our GIS layers - Class > Type > Sub Type.

Once Class has been selected I would like the Type list to be filtered to only values relevant for that class and so on for Sub-Type.

[image]

I have turned this into Code Value list attribute tables and loaded inot QGIS as attribute tables -

[image]

I have used these tables as Value Relation lists in the widget properties

[image]

The drop down lists work fine without a filter. But as soon as I try adding a filter with an expression, there is nothing in my drop down...
If I simply type "CLASS_ID" = 1 ... I do limit the list to only those for Class = 1. The expression on it's own (attribute($currentfeature, 'LU_CLASS') correctly populates the integer values if I use it to populate a virtual field in the expression builder...

Can anyone provide any guidance as to why this doesn't work in the widget filter?

I have also (briefly) tried to set up a relation in the project properties... but this feels like I am going about it the wrong way... the records aren't a child or related to this other table - I simply want to use them to populate drop-down lists.

Am I just missing a simple step?

Comment: Would this core feature already be what you want? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156039/relation-reference-to-simulate-filtered-drop-down-lists/156058#156058

Comment: Hi Matthias, this other question was also posted by me (after I had little feedback on this one and did a bit more experimentation myself) - it kind-of works, but requires far more setup and overcomplicates what should be relatively simple. As I understand it, the "relation reference" is for true parent-child dependencies, such as a pole or feature that has multiple connections to it. The suggestion below of a "$currentformfeature" expression sounds great to me, and like it would make the above situation work.

Answer (score 5):

$currentfeature refers to the related layer (Type_Values in your example) so the expression always return false and all values are filtered out.

See: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2015-November/040382.html

Comment: This sounds like a wonderful suggestion! Would be very keen to see this implemented so that the above workflow example would work :)

Comment: ermm am i missing something? nothing comes out of that link

Answer (score 4):

I've just published a plugin that allows for drill-down and other complex filtering of values in a form, have a look:

http://www.itopen.it/a-new-qgis-plugin-allows-dynamic-filtering-of-values-in-forms/

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar and in my case I made it work changing your expression:

```
"CLASS_ID" = attribute( $currentfeature, 'LU_CLASS')
```

for

```
"CLASS_ID" = current_value('LU_CLASS')
```

Brief explanation:

As **@elpaso66** noticed ***$currentfeature*** refers to the related layer (Type_Values in the example above) and we need a reference to the element being edited at the time, so we have ***current_value('field')*** function that allows us to select the value of a field in the element that we are editing.

This way we can filter the key of the related layer (Type_Values in the example above) with the value of the fileld we want to use as filter (LU_CLASS in the example above)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please present your answer in more detail so that other users can follow your solution approach more easily? Thanks!